# Access MySQL server running in Docker with its domain name

Tags: mysql, docker

I am currently configuring a MySQL database in a Docker container. There are two Docker images: one is a DNS server and the other is the MySQL database server.

Here is the docker-compose section which describes the MySQL container:

```yaml
  has-db:
    restart: unless-stopped
    network_mode: "host"
    ports:
      - "192.168.10.100:3306:3306/tcp"
    hostname: db.xxx.com
    container_name: db.xxx.com
```

I bind MySQL listening configuration to:

```
port            = 3306
bind-address    = db.xxx.com
```

Here is the table of MySQL users:

```
mysql> SELECT User, Host FROM mysql.user;
+-------------------+-----------------------------------+
| User              | Host                              |
+-------------------+-----------------------------------+
| root              | localhost                         |
| db_user           | localhost                         |
| db_user           | db.xxx.com                        |
+-------------------+-----------------------------------+
```

When I want to connect to the MySQL server using its domain name, I get the following error message:

```
mysql --port=3306 --host=db.xxx.com -u db_user -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1130 (HY000): Host '192.168.10.10' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server
```

Here, `192.168.10.10` is the IP address of the DNS server.

If I add a new user which has its `Host` field set to `192.168.10.10` it works. But that is definitely not what I want..

The IP address associated to the MySQL container is okay:

```
nslookup db.xxx.com
Server:     192.168.10.10
Address:    192.168.10.10#53

Name:   db.xxx.com
Address: 192.168.10.100
```

**Q:** How can I access MySQL server running within a Docker container using its domain name?

NOTE: I first was relying on a "localhost" configuration and everything was okay. This question comes after changing the MySQL listening address and user.

EDIT: As a temporary workaround I use the `%` sign in place of the host field. This flag means "any IP address". But I still would like to know why the DNS IP address shows up when connecting as described above ..

Comment: Docker provides its own internal DNS system; do you actually need a separate DNS server here?  In a container I'd almost always expect a bind address to be set to 0.0.0.0 ("all interfaces") and then to use Compose `ports:` to limit its external visibility.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I actually do need a DNS because I have other services which run on separates hosts.. When I use the 0.0.0.0 bind address the container binds to all interfaces on the host (because of the "host" network selection). I want it to be bound to a specific domain name (IP after DNS resolution on the host).

Comment: @DavidMaze I did another test with 0.0.0.0 and it unfortunately does not work either. I still get the Host not allowed error message with host ip being the DNS one ..

Comment: May be my.cnf problem? Something like bind-address = 127.0.0.1?

Comment: This is not especially sounding like a programming-related question; since you're disabling Docker's networking layer, it's not even really a Docker-related question.  "How do I set up DNS and a MySQL server on the same host" seems like a question that might be more suited for a more system-administration-oriented site like [sf].

Comment: @DavidMaze Indeed .. +1